# 3Ch Zigbee Switch Module

Tags: switches, components, zigbee

[image: 3Ch Zigbee Switch Module]

I’ve recently bought and installed this switch module. However, I don’t understand how closing the switch between the COM terminal and the S1 Wire closes the circuit between the live and L1. What exactly is the COM and how does this all work internally?

Comment: Probably relay coils; have you consulted the instruction sheet for the module?

Comment: @vir There aren’t any.

Comment: I would not hook anything up to line voltage in my house if it didn't come with an instruction sheet.

Comment: @vir By instruction sheet do you mean step by step instructions on how to connect the module, yes there was one. But that only showed me how to connect what  and where. There was no sheet describing the internals of the module though, is that uncommon?

Answer (score 0):

The ZT3L module looks like it has some inputs that are connected to the S1-3 inputs of the module.  It controls the three 005-1H11T relays which are connected to your outputs.

[image: internals of module]